# Calculating sample size for SEM model

Tags: sample-size, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

I am wanting to test antecedents and outcomes of a given construct through survey data.  If I anticipate using SEM, how do I calculate the necessary sample size?  I am collecting data from employees as well as customers.  I have 3 antecedents (all consisting of 4 items or less per construct), 1 mediator (my construct of interest, which consists of 4 items), and 3 outcome variables (one employee DV consisting of 3 items and two customer DVs, one with 6 items, the other with 3).  I will be conducting a one-time survey of employees as well as customers.

Answer (score 2):

There are three issues to worry about when it comes to sample size:

1. Do I have enough data to make sure that the model is identified and converges?
2. Do I have power to test particular effects of interest?
3. Do I have power to reject the null hypothesis that the model fits?

The way to mostly answer them is to do simulation. Most SEM software makes it pretty easy to simulate these days. For example, if you use Lavaan: http://simsem.org/ .